# javascript error: array.substring is not a function

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm trying to use substrings to make a phone number out of a list of 10 digits:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  var areaCode = "(" + numbers.substring(0, 4) + ")";
  var prefix = " " + numbers.substring(3, 6);
  var lineNum = "-" + numbers.substring(6);
  return areaCode + prefix + lineNum;
}

createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]);
```

jsbin returns this error:

```
"error"
"TypeError: numbers.substring is not a function
    at createPhoneNumber (xupovoy.js:8:32)
    at xupovoy.js:13:1
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.41.2.min.js:1:13926
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.41.2.min.js:1:10855"
```

Writing the return as one line yields a similar result:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  return "(" + numbers.substring(0, 4) + ") " + numbers.substring(3, 6) + "-" + numbers.substring(6);
}

createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]);
```

I think I'll also need to use `.join()` to solve this, but right now I just need help to get past this error so I can see the current output.

Comment: Arrays don't have a `.substring()` function. Perhaps you're looking for `.slice()`.

Comment: `substring` is a method for Strings, not Arrays.

Comment: *numbers* is an array, so make it a string: `numbers = numbers.join('')`.

Answer (score 2):

The substring function can only be used with strings. In order to keep working with arrays, you should use slice and then remove the commas:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  var areaCode = ("(" + numbers.slice(0, 4) + ")").replace(/,/g, "");
  var prefix = (" " + numbers.slice(3, 6)).replace(/,/g, "");
  var lineNum = ("-" + numbers.slice(6)).replace(/,/g, "");
  return areaCode + prefix + lineNum;
}
```

Another approach could be the use of `.join('')`. (Thanks @nnnnnn) This way we could remove all the replaces by one `.join` at the beginning of the function:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  numbers = numbers.join('');
  var areaCode = "(" + numbers.substring(0, 4) + ")";
  var prefix = " " + numbers.substring(3, 6);
  var lineNum = "-" + numbers.substring(6);
  return areaCode + prefix + lineNum;
}
```

The replace will search for every comma occurrence on the generated string and it will replace them by an empty string (it will basically delete them).

To learn a little more:

[Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

[Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[Substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

[Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/join)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to first `.join('')` the array with no commas?

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right! That way there is no need to repeat the replace. Will edit the answer right way with that approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with both suggestions, here's what I used:

```
function createPhoneNumber(numbers) {
  numbers = numbers.join('');
  var areaCode = numbers.substring(0, 3);
  var prefix = numbers.substring(3, 6);
  var lineNum = numbers.substring(6);
  return ("(" + areaCode + ") " + prefix + "-" + lineNum);
}

createPhoneNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]);
```

While testing, I noticed I needed to change the areaCode stop, from 4 to 3 (derp).

Thank you lovely people -- @Bruno_Santos and @nnnnnn -- for your kind assistance and the links to MDN. I learned a bunch!!!